# Why no style change in callout in position After? And why is PlotRange so badly calculated?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I thought my plot labelling issues would get resolved with the new `Callout` feature in v11 but perhaps not...and apart from the lack of styling of the callout in `After` position, the plot range for the `Before` position does not seem to be well calculated as extra space was reserved for a graphic that didn't need it.

I found I had to adjust the vertical plot range for `Above` and `Below` because there was nothing like enough space allowed for those.

I'm hoping these are glitches soon to be fixed, or am I missing something obvious here?

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[Plot[
   Callout[Cos[3 x + Pi/2], pos, pos, Appearance -> "Frame"], 
   {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}],
  {pos, {Before, After, Above, Below, Left, Right}}], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have improved a lot just by waiting for later versions of Mathematica (11.2 is the version used to produce the plot below).  The `PlotRange` is now adjusted to make room for the callout. I still don't like the positioning of `Left` or `Right` callouts, particularly where the leader seems to point in the wrong direction (but perhaps this is a deliberate design choice).

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[Plot[
   Callout[Cos[3 x + Pi/2], pos, pos, Appearance -> "Frame"], {x, -5, 5},
   ImageSize -> 300], {pos, {Before, After, Above, Below, Left, 
    Right}}], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]